# Reverse an edge split?

Tags: modeling

I applied an edge split a while ago on my model and now I want to separate parts of it. It's going to take me a long time to individually select each face because none of the edges are touching the other. So I can't use some of the auto-select features in Blender...

Comment: Enter Edit mode > Select All > Press W > Remove Doubles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can <kbd>Tab</kbd> into *Edit Mode*, key <kbd>A</kbd> once or twice until everything is selected, key <kbd>W</kbd> to open the *Specials* menu and select *Remove Doubles*.